# i can access other guard data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-guard

i have problem when access api with guard. i have define 2 guards those are customer-api and pegawai-api. The problem is when i login using pegawai i can access api link with customer-api guard, and when i login with customer token i can access api link with pegawai-api

this is routes/api.php

```
Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('register/customer', 'registerCustomer');
    Route::post('register/pegawai', 'registerPegawai');
    Route::post('login', 'login');

    // Route after login
    Route::middleware(['auth:customer-api,pegawai-api'])->group(function () {
        Route::post('logout', 'logout');
        Route::post('change-password', 'changePassword');
    });
});

Route::middleware(['auth:pegawai-api'])->group(function () {

    Route::controller(KamarController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('kamar', 'index');
        Route::post('kamar', 'store');
        Route::get('kamar/{id}', 'show');
        Route::put('kamar/{id}', 'update');
        Route::delete('kamar/{id}', 'destroy');
    });
});

Route::middleware(['auth:customer-api'])->group(function () {

    Route::controller(CustomerController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('customer', 'show');
        Route::put('customer', 'update');
    });
});
```

this is Models/Customer.php

```
class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $table = "customer";

    protected $guard = 'customer-api';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_jenis_customer',
        'no_identitas',
        'jenis_identitas',
        'nama_institusi',
        'nama',
        'email',
        'password',
        'no_telp',
        'alamat',
    ];
    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
}
```

This is Models/Pegawai.php

```
class Pegawai extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $table = "pegawai";

    protected $guard = 'pegawai';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_role',
        'nama',
        'email',
        'password',
        'no_telp',
        'alamat',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function role($role)
    {
        if($this->id_role == $role){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

this is Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     */
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
    }

}
```

This is config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'pegawai-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'pegawais',
        ],
        'pegawai' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'pegawais',
        ],
        'customer-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],

    ],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'pegawais' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Pegawai::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],

],
```

this is Http/Controllers/AuthControllers to check login credentials

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $loginData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        if(Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($loginData)){
            $token = Auth::guard('customer')->user()->createToken('AuthToken')->accessToken;
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Login Success',
                'data' => Auth::guard('customer')->user(),
                'token' => $token,
            ], 200);
        }


        if(Auth::guard('pegawai')->attempt($loginData)){
            $token = Auth::guard('pegawai')->user()->createToken('AuthToken')->accessToken;
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Login Success',
                'data' => Auth::guard('pegawai')->user(),
                'token' => $token,
            ], 200);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'Invalid Credentials',
        ], 401);
    }
```

Comment: how does the login know which guard to use? also why are there login and logout endpoints?

Comment: i've add the login function. if the user login it will check which guard attempt the login